# Generate Sequence Datetime using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, but I need to generate a sequence of minutes from the system time. For example, I need a function that takes the current system time, and generates a vector of the last 60 minutes of that hour, v `[21:00, 20:59, 20:58, 20:57, ....]`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This function return an array of last 60 minutes from the current time.

```
function last60Minutes() {
  var count = 60;
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
  var currentMinute = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var array = [];
  while(count > 0) {
    if (currentMinute >= 0) {
      var formattedMinute = currentMinute.toString().length < 2 ? '0'+currentMinute : currentMinute;
      var formattedHour = currentHour.toString().length < 2 ? '0'+currentHour : currentHour;
      array.push(formattedHour+':'+formattedMinute);
    } else if (currentHour > 0) {
      currentHour--;
      currentMinute = 59;
      var formattedHour = currentHour.toString().length < 2 ? '0'+currentHour : currentHour;
      array.push(formattedHour+':'+currentMinute);
    } else {
      currentHour = 23;
      currentMinute = 59;
      array.push(currentHour+':'+currentMinute);
    }
    currentMinute--;
    count--;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Of course you can clean it up a little.

Running in the browser console gave me this result:

```
last60Minutes()
["20:20", "20:19", "20:18", "20:17", "20:16", "20:15", "20:14", "20:13", "20:12", "20:11", "20:10", "20:09", "20:08", "20:07", "20:06", "20:05", "20:04", "20:03", "20:02", "20:01", "20:00", "19:59", "19:58", "19:57", "19:56", "19:55", "19:54", "19:53", "19:52", "19:51", "19:50", "19:49", "19:48", "19:47", "19:46", "19:45", "19:44", "19:43", "19:42", "19:41", "19:40", "19:39", "19:38", "19:37", "19:36", "19:35", "19:34", "19:33", "19:32", "19:31", "19:30", "19:29", "19:28", "19:27", "19:26", "19:25", "19:24", "19:23", "19:22", "19:21"]
```